# How to open the specific diagram type

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have added the compiled mdg file in C#now I want to create the specific diagram type.So what value should i use to create the specific diagram object which is specified in mdg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the stereotype of the diagram:

```
newDia = package.Diagrams.AddNew("name", "yourMDGid::yourDiaName")
```